# Why cannot opinion-based questions be answered or implemented here?

Tags: discussion, opinion-based

We can treat them in a lot of ways.

Suggestion: (Skip to save brain power) the OP will choose whether the question is opinion-based or not at the start. When the OP chooses that it is opinion-based, then every answer posted in the question will have another score that ranges from 0% to 100% (apart from quality, standard, whatever score, but parallel) that is calculated by the ratio between those that agree and disagree, and of course there will be two buttons for choosing whether you agree or disagree. For the OP the feature 'Best Answer' will be disabled, and the best ratio towards agree will be at the top. Another thing, it's obvious, but the agree,  disagree, or agreement-score-thing won't be implemented to the question's post.

Why wasn't something like this suggestion implemented? It looks like there's something very basic that won't let it happen. The Q&A thing is OK, you just eliminate the 'Best Answer' thing and add something that takes its place.

Comment: Why do you think that SE must do everything?

Comment: There are dozens of other sites where you can have discussions, ask for opinions, and express your own. We're not one of them, and hopefully never will become one. This is a technical resource and knowledge base, not a chat room or discussion group. If that's what you want, go to one of the other sites instead. (Ironically, this exact topic has in fact been *discussed* many times here and on [meta.se] previously, and every time it gets answered the same way.)

Comment: @KenWhite This is not for discussion, it's just that everyone puts his opinions and\or shows whatever s\he is agreeing or disagreeing with outer's opinions by using the buttons. They won't discuss to put their opinion at the top. The ONLY discussion will be on fixing the post or similar things.

Comment: As I said, there are dozens of other sites out there that ask for opinions and allow discussion of those opinions. Use them instead of here. You offer an opinion on a matter, someone doesn't agree, they comment, you comment back, and it's now a discussion. Go visit a social networking site if that's what you want. We don't do that here. Search for some of the previous questions I referenced before, and read the reasons why we don't allow them. There's no point in **discussing it** here yet again. This is not a "here's my opinion", "here's what I like", or "let's collect a list of things" site.

Comment: @KenWhite You just got the wrong idea and wrote a lot of things about it. I meant questions that is similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689/recommended-fonts-for-programming you can't see a way that they aren't neseccery\helping.

Comment: I saw the exact question you linked (about fonts) the first time you linked it. It's inappropriate here - it's a "list" question, asking people to list their favorite things. It's full of links, opinions about what's the best or personal favorite, and totally meaningless for technical value. I did not misunderstand anything, and meant exactly what I said - if you want a social networking site, go elsewhere to find one. SO is not one of them, and hopefully never will be. If that's a problem for you, please feel free to ask for a full refund  here and take your business elsewhere. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite 'You just got the wrong idea' once again, I HATE Facebook. Anyway it's beginning to be meanless discussion because this site already gave it a try and failed. (It didn't contributed as I thought it would)

Comment: Just to let you know you're not alone: I'm completely with you. I guess the problem is just that SE does not scale well, and as a consequence we have content limitations that are draconian compared to early days. C'est la vie.

Answer (score 18):

It doesn't fit in with the goal or intent of Stack Exchange, which is to provide expert answers to questions.

Not just that, but experts aren't necessarily going to be willing to answer something that's completely based on opinion or subjectivity.  There are many ways to go something in software engineering, and the hope is that the best approaches and practices rise to the top, which is why subjective questions don't fit well here.

Further, what would be the use from a question like that?  What would someone reading Stack Overflow hope to gain from a question that's open-ended?  What would an expert contributing to these hope to share if every other expert has given their opinion, and some of them are crap, and some of them are good, and some of them are just in left field?

I don't see the value.

Comment: You can have a lot of uses in it. For example `What is the best way to do X?`. You could actually open new type of questions to stack overflow. I can't just give them off my head, but you can make good uses out of that sort of questions.

Comment: "Best way" is the very definition of subjective.  There's no one good answer to "best way", and you'll discourage a lot of experts since they know that, and you'll discourage a lot of enthusiasts because they don't *know* the best way.

Comment: That's the thing about the opinion-based questions, you can't answer it while being 100% sure, but it will show the one that is the closest (By the users' feedback of course) towards the best way, or towards whatever question's point. It will be good for those users that want to be in the majority or hearing others' way of doing things.

Comment: And that's what I have a problem with.  That sort of question is untenable here.

Comment: I see your point. (Because *this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion* thing) But I will show you an (existing) example how it could make good questions that will help. The example:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689/recommended-fonts-for-programming When I felt like there could be better font for me than Consolas that question helped me a lot. That question could be opinion-based but still it could help to some users. EDIT: A bit irony in this discussion...

Comment: Yes...which is why that question hasn't been deleted, but has a historical lock on it.  It's also a question that's ***really*** old, and shouldn't be considered an example of anything that we want to still happen on Stack Overflow.