# Dealing with a question that reads opinion-based, but could be of use to others

Tags: discussion, opinion-based

I stumbled across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30132220/1079354) not that long ago (*really* not that long ago).  It seems like it's an interesting and novel approach to something that someone in Java may want to deal with at some point, which is avoiding generics via method overloading.

The main issue is that it's not a question, or in the Q&A format.  It even ends with

> Any other ideas?

I **really** want to keep content like this around, but I wouldn't know where to begin editing it/guiding the OP along to get them to write this as a question.  Does anyone have any guidance in this manner?

Note that this question isn't to ask, "Why can't we have opinionated questions here on Stack Overflow?".  This question is to help guide myself and others in the future on what to do in a situation in which we feel like a question *could* work on Stack Overflow, but needs a non-trivial and potentially invasive amount of editing to bring it to standards.

Comment: That's the point.  It's *not* asking anything.  But it contains useful information.

Comment: Looks like it could easily be a self-answer: "How to avoid generics in Java?" Ideally with some real-world reason you would want to do so.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET: Does one have to supply a real-world reason for it?  I see this being more in-line with a blog post-esque sort of question/answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why opinion-based questions cannot be answered or implemented here?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274762/why-opinion-based-questions-cannot-be-answered-or-implemented-here)

Comment: @gnat:  Not a dupe.  I very well know why  questions of that sort can't work here.  But, I feel like this question has a chance.  (Ironically, I *answered* the suggested duplicate.)

Comment: @Makoto That's paradoxical.

Comment: [an Atwood transform](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6744/31260)? "You've found a poor question that you really think has some merit to it. What things are needed to successfully do this transformation of making a poor question into a good one?"

Comment: I don't see the paradox.  The question is worded in such a way that it is opinionated (specifically because of the one line at the end), but overall can be brought to standards if it has a concise question.  My question is how would I be able to approach a scenario like this, as I definitely want to edit it into shape, but the edit would be ***extremely*** invasive.

Comment: _"I find this code ugly"_ is an opinion, but _"How to shorten this"_ isn't.

Comment: @gnat:  I've never heard of the so-called "Atwood transform", so I might consider that as an approach.

Comment: I would think a real-world example would make it a much better question. Basically, "How to avoid generics" seems a pretty poor question off the cuff, so I was trying to provide an example to make it better.

Comment: FWIW for _transform_ to work more reliably, [question would better be on hold](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161877/165773): "fast closure here serves the primary need to make reopening easier and protect the poorly worded good question from getting bad answers"

Comment: I'm not so sure about that.  The main issue here is that if it were put on hold, one couldn't add the answer block as a Community Wiki.  That's why I'm reluctant to VTC on it myself, as the very tool meant to safeguard situations like this would actually hurt more.

Comment: if you are comfortable running against fastest gun garbage (that may block salvaging edits), then why not, keep it open. My past experience with this made me prefer to close and delay answer until after reopen

Comment: Right...so now the question is in a state where it *can't* be fixed, or at least it can't be fixed in a way that would preserve the existing content.  To fix it, someone would have to remove *a lot* of the content in the question and practically babysit it until it get enough reopen votes.  Talk about disheartening.

Comment: Related on Meta.SE: [Suggestions for editing old not constructive question into constructiveness so it can be preserved](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141006)

Answer (score 7):

Not all useful content needs to be on SO.  If you think there is useful information there, but it isn't a question meeting SO's standards for a question, then simply have the content in another location.  Find a forum to discuss the issue, since it's trying to hold a discussion, or have it posted as a blog, etc.  Find a medium that is actually designed to support the interactions intended by this content.

Comment: I'm bewildered by your assertion that not all useful content needs to be on SO.  It seems to run counter to [what the mission of Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) actually is.  I don't disagree that not all content is fit for SO, but out of the hundreds and thousands of questions I've seen that fall into the same pattern, this one at least has a *chance*.

Comment: @Makoto A mission statement can only be a few sentences.  it doesn't exactly have a lot of room for subtlety or to clarify what the entire scope of the site is.  SE has made it very clear that SO's mission very explicitly excludes *discussions*, and plenty of other categories of questions/content simply because the site isn't suited to handling them, even though such content can potentially have value.  SE is not the only site on the internet; there is in fact room for other sites to also have useful content on them.

Comment: If we removed the discussion, then it'd be **fine**.  Again, I'm well aware of the subtleties and intricacies of Stack Overflow.  The main thing here is how one would approach fixing this question.  It **can** be brought on-topic.

Comment: @Makoto If you remove the discussion then there is no information.  It's an answer searching for a question.  SO isn't Jeopardy.

Comment: I don't...see that being true **at all**...  I'm trying my best not to misunderstand you, but where do you see "discussion" outside of "Any more suggestions?"  I see a blurb about what use case/pain a user has run into for something like this, and I see a block discussing what steps one could take to mitigate that pain.  Then at the very end I see the "discussion" bit.  Have I missed something critical here?

Comment: @Makoto Sorry, when I said "information" i meant to say "question".  There is no *question* there without the discussion prompt.

Comment: Okay, now I see where you're at.  To that end, I still disagree; the first paragraph can be rephrased such that it reads as a question.  The main driving point here is how one would approach a question in this scenario, so that there *can* be a question here to accompany this answer.