# Understanding the rule against “primarily opinion based” questions

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

**Background:** I have used the Stack Overflow (SO) site many times in the past, usually being directed there by search engines when looking for an answer. Some of the best answers I have found were in questions which had been closed as "primarily opinion based". Hence I feel that the site is missing a big potential by disallowing some of these questions.

Recently I decided to get an SO account and again I am struggling with the definition of "primarily opinion based". The first question I asked could potentially be seen as "primarily opinion based", so I tried to formulate the question as objectively as possible and set up objective criteria for the answer. Still the question was quickly put on hold by three other users, and I had to realize that I did not fully understand why (see comments under the above linked question).

I think I understand the purpose of this rule. Many fora are polluted by endless arguments which are essentially about opinion rather than facts, and I acknowledge that SO has managed to keep relatively clean of such discussions.

However, I think it is difficult to understand the definition of the rule. Fundamentally I think the definition of "primarily opinion based" opens a huge grey zone making it difficult to determine on beforehand whether or not a given question breaks this rule. As I see it, the rule is more about the potential answers than about the question itself hence the vote for or against a "primarily opinion based" question is itself a primarily opinion based response.

Can anyone explain the objective criteria which dictates whether or not a question is "primarily opinion based"?

---

Edit: I removed the link to the original SO question since this discussion apparently has triggered some people to downvote that.

Comment: If questions can be answered in lots of different ways, each of which disagree with each other that's a good sign for primarily opinion based.

Comment: What Robert says... and if there's no way *prove* a suggestion is correct because it's subjective. If a question asks "better" or "best", that's also a red flag, unless there are measurable criteria that can be used (speed, perhaps).

Comment: That question could well be the canonical for a "primary opinion based" question.  Anybody's list is a correct answer.  The key is that you thought about it, grouped accordingly, and that's good enough.  The only way to not do it right is not thinking about it.  Which happens, but is not the topic of the question.  Just in case: SO will almost never help when a question is triggered by a disagreement about coding style between team members.

Comment: [How can I encourage Stack Overflow to rein in the 'subjective' vigilantes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167516)

Comment: @HansPassant Good comment. If you are right then I think that is a problem (which is one reason why I raised this question), because then the only thing preventing lengthy discussions about whether or not a given question is "primarily opinion based" is that SO does not provide a mechanism for this (people vote for and against without providing their rationale). Maybe the answer is simply that: yes, it is opinion-based whether or not a question is opinion-based. The same goes for up/down votes. For better or worse, that is the way the site works.

Comment: @RobertLongson There is no reason to make this about me against everyone else. I have never written that I think it was wrong that my question got voted as "primarily opinion based", it is probably correct and I accept that. What I am saying is that I do not understand it and I am therefore asking for clarification of the rules here.

Comment: I'm merely pointing out that generally people do think this is pretty clear.

Comment: see also [Why opinion-based questions cannot be answered or implemented here?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274762/839601) and [Why do 'some examples' and 'list of things' questions get closed?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7538/31260)

Comment: @RobertLongson It is a funny fact that many things are clear until you try to define them (e.g. we all know what it means that something is "alive", but try to look up the definition). I think this is one of those cases. I thank you and all others for your time and efforts.

Comment: @gnat Thanks for finding this, I agree it is a duplicate, and luckily it contains a very interesting discussion even though it was closed as "too broad" (no I will not start a discussion about that :) ).

Comment: From reading a couple of your comments I think there *may* be a misunderstanding about to what "primarily opinion-based" applies. It's that the question is an opinion, it's that any response to it will necessarily be an opinion. The question can only elicit opinions and not hard-and-fast answers.

Comment: @CindyMeister Thanks, I think I understand this distinction, however, the SO system does apply this classification to questions.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have had to remove the link to the SO question because me raising this question in Meta SO apparently has meant that the SO question is now getting downvotes.

Comment: 1) It has to apply the reason to the question as the question, since any responses will be opinions, needs to be put in a state that will not allow responses and eventually be removed from view. 2) This is known as "the Meta effect" and can be much, much worse. Do keep in mind that the link remains available through the "revisions" interface - not that I think it's a problem, given the very few Meta effect downvotes...

Comment: @CindyMeister 1) Thanks, I do understand this. What confused me is that I took care in asking a question in a way where I thought I was requesting objective answers, but it appears most people understand it differently, and in that case SO is a democracy for better or worse (mostly "better", I guess :-)) - 2) It seems I am learning some lessons here.

Comment: Objective rules/criteria explain what *you* should do when you judge if something is primarily opinion based or not, they do not necessarily explain why people make the choices that they make. To maybe get a better idea of the latter, it can be of help to research some existing cases of "why was this question closed as primarily opinion based?" on meta, there should be plenty.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We [tried creating a site for opinionated questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3412/what-is-the-history-behind-the-site-scope-change-from-npr-to-conceptual-questio). It failed because nobody could/would moderate it. The site became overwhelmed with joke questions, joke answers and flame wars. It was eventually relaunched with a different scope, you can read a more detailed history in [the link](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3415).

The [help centre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) says you should

> avoid asking questions where every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”

If questions can be answered in lots of different ways, each of which disagree with each other, that's what will generally happen. If you found such a question and read each of its answers, what have you learned other than, "it's your call".

Generally questions such as what's your favourite..., what's the best..., tend to run aground like this.

Even what's the fastest has problems. Fastest with what memory? On what operating system? With what compiler compiling it? How many CPUs? What compiler version? And if you nail all that down, how useful is your question to a) others right now or b) even you next year when you've moved on to a new computer and new compiler.

Comment: This is a good answer, but it does not help me understand the concrete case where my question was rejected. To me it is clear that e.g. "What is the best way to increment an integer by 1 in C"? is opinion-based while "What is the fastest way to increment a 32 bit integer on an 80x86 CPU?" should be OK. What about this question (which I see as equivalent to the question I got rejected): "How to increment an integer by 1 in C?". It has different answers, but I am not asking for the best, I am asking if solutions exist and, if so, one or more possible solutions (continues...)

Comment: ... I cannot avoid that other people could get into a lengthy discussion whether `a=a+1` or`a++` is better, but would I still not call the *question* opinion-based because it is objective whether or not a given answer is correct. If I am right about this(?) maybe my problem is a matter of complexity since my question (essentially) "how to divide C statements into an ordered set of categories" is much more complicated than "how to increment an integer" and thus more at risk of creating an opinion-based discussion. I am still in doubt, though.

Comment: Everyone has their own opinion on what categories to choose and in which way to order them. None of these is objectively "better" than any other way. It's another "what's the best..." question.

Comment: Sorry if I am slow, but that would mean you would also reject the question about "how to increment an integer by 1" because there are more solutions and none is objectively better than the other? Or is it about the complexity/degree of open-endedness?